# Python/pygame - turning images into video

Tags: python, video, camera, pygame, image

I am using the Pygame module in  python to take pictures with my webcam. The problem is that I would like to export a video file (don't care what type) to use elsewhere. Since pygame cannot export video directly, I guess that there is two ways to do it:

1. Somehow stitch the photos Pygame creates into a video. (my preferred method)
2. Use an external library.

I only need 4 frames per second, and I don't care about the picture quality.

How can I make a video with python / pygame?

Comment: Maybe you want a program like http://camstudio.org/, it captures a region on your desktop and saves it to a movie file. I can also think of a few other scenarios where that's useful.

Comment: What operating system do you use? There is no way to do what you want from Pygame, but it can be done using external libraries. Once I know your OS, I should be able to write a helpful answer.

Comment: I am using the default os (linux debian wheezy) on the raspberry pi.

Comment: I am using ffmpeg to create a video file and it's pretty intuitive once you get the hang of it. Obviously lots of jpg files all over no not the prettiest solution but it is powerful enough. The solution offered by @samurait using pymedia looks cleaner if you intend to distribute your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem and am searching the solution.

I found [this](http://pymedia.org/tut/src/make_video.py.html)

This seems work well though I didn't try yet.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it uses PyMedia looking at the imports, so I'll give it a try